# I want the sentence and the time in same line

Tags: javascript, html, time

Can someone help me with this. I want the words and the time scrolling at the same line because the one that i did is not joined together.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Time</title>
</head>
<body>

<marquee bgcolor="blue" width"1000" height="50"> 
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script><body onload="startTime()"> <div id="txt"></div> Philippine Standard Time (GMT+0800)</marquee>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Time</title>
</head> 


<body onload="startTime()"> 
<marquee bgcolor="blue" width"1000" height="50"> 
<div>
  <span id="txt"></span>
  <span>Philippine Standard Time (GMT+0800)</span>
</div>
</marquee>

<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding style `#txt {
    display: inline-block;
}` for display div inline with other text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Time</title>
</head>
<body>

<marquee bgcolor="blue" width"1000" height="50"> 
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " Philippine Standard Time (GMT+0800)";
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;

}
</script><body onload="startTime()"> <div id="txt"></div>  </marquee>

</body>
</html>
```

Instead of using Javascript to load the time alone, and the other strings using HTML, you'd better use Javascript for both. Hope it helps...